# Best way to deal with multilabel features in pipelines of scikit

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline

Hello I am dealing with some features that are multilabel. Tags. I want to train a regressor but I don't know which is the properly way to encode the tags. I tried MultiLabelBinarizer but I am not able to achieve this from inside my pipeline. Theres is no problem if I encode it outside the pipeline. I want to keep using my pipeline because I use FeatureUnion a lot and it is very confortable this way.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: As well as a data sample?